# How to get the title of wordpress post in php

Tags: php, wordpress, post, get, title

How can i get the title of WordPress post in this php code

```
 <?php include("imdb.php");   $imdb = new Imdb(); $movieArray =
 $imdb->getMovieInfo("**.get_the_title().**"); echo '<table
 cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" border="1" width="80%"
 align="center">'; foreach ($movieArray as $key=>$value){
     $value = is_array($value)?implode("<br />", $value):$value;
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<th align="left" valign="top">' . strtoupper($key) . '</th><td>' . $value . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>'; } echo '</table>'; ?>
```

I tried to put `".get_the_title()."` but don't result the title of current post.

Comment: what's with ** at begin and end?

Comment: i don't have this ** in my php code... just here in question show up

Comment: yes, in single.php file from wordpress theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your code is in a wordpress loop, so you just have to use :

```
$imdb->getMovieInfo(get_the_title());
```

Using `$imdb->getMovieInfo("**.get_the_title().**");` don't work since PHP don't handle function inside strings : http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_title()` function requires that you pass it an `$id` if you are not in **the loop**. If you are in the loop, and want to use the current post's id for getting the title, then you can call the function with out passing anything.

See [`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title), [`the_loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).